# How to make a rainbow border with CSS in a rounded image?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to do this, with CSS, just for fun and learning.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wrMt.jpg)

Do you think it is possible to achieve it only with CSS?
What would be the path you would take if not?

Comment: It gives a 404 error. Can you please show us what you have tried till now?

Comment: thanks, I just edited it

Comment: I have achieved results with javascript, however I have the doubt if it is possible to do it with css @Paulie_D

Comment: Not possible with just CSS.  The closest you might get is with CSS `mask-image` and SVG's but the problem is the rainbow gradients behind.  You can't make gradients exactly like that with just CSS.  You could make something with a similar effect, but not the way that is where the gradients are neither linear or radial, they are arbitrary and human-designed.

Comment: Not saying it's a great idea and it may not be simple but could you not adapt something like this and eventually get there? https://codepen.io/enesser/pen/GcChq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do it, you can use svg to achieve it. Create transparent circles, apply gradient to their strokes and finally position them using transform to achieve desired result. Best thing is that since the circles are SVG's they won't get pixelated but the problem is that it is tedious work and not worth it unless needed. Hence the best way to achieve it will be using a png format of the image.

```html
</head>

<body>
  <svg id="c1" height="150" width="400">    
    
    <g transform="translate(20,30)">
     <defs>
       <linearGradient id="grad2" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
         <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,153);stop-opacity:1" />
         <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(102,255,51);stop-opacity:1" />
       </linearGradient>
     </defs>
     <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" stroke="url(#grad2)" fill="transparent" />
    </g>

     <g>
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
          <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1" />
          <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
     <circle  id="c2" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" stroke="url(#grad1)" fill="transparent" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can use CSS animations to change the border color.

```css
#image-id {
  border: solid 1vw;
  animation: rainbow 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rainbow {
  0% { border-color: color1 }
  10% { border-color: color2 }
  20% { border-color: color3 }
  30% { border-color: color4 }
  40% { border-color: color5 }
  50% { border-color: color4 }
  30% { border-color: color7 }
  70% { border-color: color8 }
  80% { border-color: color9 }
  90% { border-color: color10 }
  100% { border-color: color11 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <img id="image-id" src="imageurl"></img>
</body>
</html>
```

That will cycle through 11 colors (replace the colors with your own).